# Method to convert an Arraylist into a Set

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I coded the following method to convert my Arraylist into a set:

```
public static Set<Animal> toSet(){
    Set<Animal> aniSet = new HashSet<Animal>(animals);
    return aniSet;
}
```

I would like to do this instead :

```
public static Set<Animal> toSet(){
    return HashSet<Animal>(animals);
}
```

Why do i get an error message that says it cannot find variable HashSet ? Do i need to store a variable first ?

EDIT : had to add new before my Hashset. Coding makes me feel so dumb :')

Comment: you forgot `new`

Comment: as well as the fact that `animals` have to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

1. You forget that the `animals` have to come from somewhere; I don't think the first example compiles either; and
2. you forgot to use `new` when creating a new `HashSet<Animal>`.

This is probably the intended behavior:

```
public static <T> Set<T> toSet(Collection<? extends T> data){
    return new HashSet<T>(data);
}
```

You can then call it with:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
//do something with the animals list
//...

Set<Animal> theSet = Foo.<Animal>toSet(animals);
```

by using a generic static method, you can call it with any type you like. By using `Collection<? extends T>` you are furthermore not limited to an `ArrayList<T>`, but you can use any kind of `Collection` (`LinkedList`, `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, ...). Finally the type of that collection does not even have to be animal. You could convert an `ArrayList<Cat>` into a `HashSet<Animal>`.

Note however that there is not much use in this method: calling it is not much shorter than using the constructor directly. The only real advantage I see is that you *encapsulate* which `Set<T>` you are going to use, such that if you later change your mind to `TreeSet<T>` all methods calling this `toSet` method will generate a `TreeSet<T>` instead of a `HashSet<T>`.